# Getting height of an absolute DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to the the `height` attribute of an absolute positioned DIV with a non predefined height attribute.

The height of the `div` depends on its dynamic content.

I've seen that `.height()` function of jQuery doesn't return the correct height of an absolute positioned `div`.

```
$(this).height()  //not working well
```

Is there any way to get its height?

Thanks.

Comment: It works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/DLJQu/  You must have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: `height()` should work. Do you have any padding on that div?

Comment: Nothing. Same result.

Comment: Is there anything in the div?

Comment: @Archer you were right. My mistake. It's about padding. It works well with `$(this).outerHeight()` thanks.

Comment: @Diodeus you can add the solution. You were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some content inside the div or at least define some minimum height in order to get the css height property—which is otherwise undefined.

The `.height()` gets the computed height for the element and thus needs some predefining.

Alternatives are the `.innerHeight()` and `.outerHeight()` methods. They might work better if you are working with the default content-box style.

Comment: both won't work with absolute position