# Height auto, when calculating in Jquery, resulting 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set my div height as auto and when I am calculating, it is giving result as 0
Here is my `css`

```
.final_event_detail {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1700px;
    opacity:0.9;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

And here is JQ

```
var mydivheight = $(".final_event_detail").height();
alert(mydivheight);
```

I tried `innerHeight` and `outerHeight` as well with no luck.

Comment: are you using `$(document).ready();` ?

Comment: Could you provide a sample? Or at least some more code / HTML. And make sure you dont have floated elements inside your div, this could cause it to have an height of 0.

Comment: No... But this is under page condition like if this is the page then calculate...

Comment: Then you should put your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ your code here })`

Comment: It's like a div which will open on a button click on the page with black background, that's why it is absolute.

Comment: I tried putting my code to in ready function but the result is same.

Comment: @mauzzamali  : please provide me working demo

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985936/getting-height-of-an-absolute-div-with-jquery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8cc4wgjt/3/  This is what i come up with and to my surprise, it is working good here but not sure why it is not working in my code. I have multiple div in my main div and none of the div has height but their child div has height.

Comment: do u have any empty divs, class name as 'final_event_detail' before this div. bcoz its take the first div class name as 'final_event_detail'  height only.